# Waiting for an element to appear in a Helium script

Tags: python, selenium, helium

I use [Helium](https://github.com/mherrmann/selenium-python-helium) to automate a web page. The problem is that I sometimes get a `LookupError` because an element is not yet present on the page when Helium searches for it. Is there a way to wait until the element is there?

Comment: Can you include a minimum reproducible example to your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wait_until(...)`. For example:

```
wait_until(Button('Download').exists)
```